# problemas al crear un link en javascript

Tags: javascript, href, enlace

Tengo este código.

```
eventClick: function(info){
        $('#visualizar #id').text(info.event.id);
        $('#visualizar #title').text(info.event.title);
        $('#visualizar #start').text(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar #end').text(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
        $('#visualizar').modal('show');
      }
```

De forma que cuando creo un  me imprime el valor de id. Ahora lo que necesito es hacer que el id sea un link al xxx.php?id='numero id'. Alguien me puede ayudar? Grac

Comment: Perdón, lo que necesito es que al mostrar 
<dd id='id'></dd>
me cree el link a xxx.php?id='numero id'.

Comment: No se entiende: ¿que el id sea un link? ¿que al mostrar una cosa te cree un link a otra? Por favor pulsa en [edit] y formula la pregunta con más claridad. Gracias.

Comment: Si. Bueno lo que quería es que el ID fuera un link al id de avería. Que me llevara por GET el id.Ya está solucionado.
```
 function verAveria(){
    window.location = 'averia.php?id='+document.getElementById('id').textContent;
 }
```
MIL GRACIAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
 function verAveria(){
    window.location = 'averia.php?id='+document.getElementById('id').textContent;
 }
```

Es que al llevar tantas horas seguidas uno se nubla la vista... jejejeje